# Implementation of Hidden Markov Model for GENE Prediction in Python

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, dna-sequence, hmmlearn

I am working on my college project where i need to find out the gene in the DNA with the help of Hidden Markov model. I am trying to implement the algorithm using the hmm-learn where i fails every time. 
Can you please tell me how to do the code implementation of Hmm in python to predict the gene in DNA. How to train the model and how to find the gene.(Tutorials will also help)

Currently i am working on the Bacillus anthracis str DNA Dataset.
Here is the  link for the dataset

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AP007209.1

Thanks for the help.